# Getting route name from tab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I want to get the name of the current route to disable the hardware back button only in the screen Home (below). So I want to get the name of current screen. If it's 'Home', the hardware back button is disabled. If not, do nothing.

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    var currentScreen = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;

    if(currentScreen === 'Home'){
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true);
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
)}
```

But I get this error:

TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.state.routeName'

What can I do to fix it? If you guys have suggestions of blocking the back button, I would accept.

**update**

I did this:

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onBackClicked = this._onBackClicked.bind(this);
    }
  
    componentWillUnmount() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackClicked);
    }
  
    _onBackClicked = () => {
      return true;
    };
  
    render() {
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(8, 0, 122, 0.91)'}}
          screenOptions={({route}) => {
            if (route.name === 'Home') {
            
            Alert.alert(route.name);

              BackHandler.addEventListener(
                'hardwareBackPress',
                this.onBackClicked,
              );
            } else {
              BackHandler.removeEventListener(
                'hardwareBackPress',
                this.onBackClicked,
              );
            }
          }}>
```

And I put an Alert to see the route name, but it brings me nothing. I suppose that's what troubles me.

**By now I just have it:**

```
export default class TabNavigator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onBackClicked = this._onBackClicked.bind(this);
    }
  
    componentWillUnmount() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackClicked);
    }
  
    _onBackClicked = () => {
      return true;
    };
  
    render() {
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(8, 0, 122, 0.91)'}}
          screenOptions={({route}) => {
            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              BackHandler.addEventListener(
                'hardwareBackPress',
                this.onBackClicked,
              );
            } else {
              BackHandler.removeEventListener(
                'hardwareBackPress',
                this.onBackClicked,
              );
            }
          }}>

        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="home" size={30} color="rgb(253, 234, 223)" />
          ),}}/>    
     )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class TabNavigator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onBackClicked = this._onBackClicked.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackClicked);
  }

  _onBackClicked = () => {
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        barStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(8, 0, 122, 0.91)'}}
        screenOptions={({navigation, route}) => {
          if (route.name === 'Home' && navigation.isFocused()) {
            BackHandler.addEventListener(
              'hardwareBackPress',
              this.onBackClicked,
            );
          } else if (route.name !== 'Home' && navigation.isFocused()) {
            BackHandler.removeEventListener(
              'hardwareBackPress',
              this.onBackClicked,
            );
          }
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
              <Icon name="home" size={30} color="rgb(253, 234, 223)" />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

I use the route prop to get the current name and `navigation.isFocused()` to check if the current route name is "Home". If this is the case I add the event that disables the hardware back button. If the route name is not home, but it is focused the I remove the event listener. Lastly I remove the event listener when the component unmounts to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: I found some problems with my original code and updated my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! What If a switch to tab settings and switch to Home again. If I press hardware back button it has to come back to settings again, but I doesn't. Can you help just one more time, please?

Comment: That contradicts with what you asked for in the original question. If you remove the `else if` statement what you asked for happens, but it's still unclear to me what behavior you actually want.

Comment: The home screen just can't go back to the login screen, but it can go back to other screen

Comment: If this is all about making sure you can't go back to the login page after authentication you can try to just disable BackHandler inside the `Home` component itself. Otherwise you can try something like this reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.